# Similar URI but different components - React Router V4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

I use `React Router V4` in my project and I want some routes like these with different components :

`/content/:type`

`/content/view/:id/:title?`

Can I do this? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are familiar with React Router basics,You can try out something like this.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/content/:type" component={ComponentA} />
    <Route exact path="/content/view/:id/:title" component={ComponentB} />
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Don't forget to import components before using them for defining routes.